# .NET: How does the use of components in .NET differ to pre-.NET?

Tags: .net, com, dll

How does the use of components in .NET differ to pre-.NET?

Are the differences as follows?

- .NET components don't have to be centrally registered on a machine and can merely be invoked at run-time from a specified location
- if .NET components are 'registered' in the GAC, problems associated with different versions of the same DLL ("DLL hell") are avoided because each version will have its own id/key which is known to the calling program

Is the above correct?

What other relevant differences are there?

Comment: well for one, they're a hell of a lot easier to use

Comment: The .Net libraries were very well designed for ease-of-use, and are lightyears easier to use than what we had before (the difference is much more pronounced between C++ and C# than between VB and VB.Net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differences given in the question are the most relevant.  Other differences relate only to ease of use with IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

In the era of COM, one could host the DLL as a DCOM service and could invoke the service hosted in one m/c from another.
After web services gained popularity, DCOM has become obsolete.

Comment: Yes, but you can do this same thing with WCF.

Comment: not as easily,and rightly so, not many people want to deal with tcp based wcf remoted components.